# Why is there a space between block elements?

Tags: html, css

So I am aware that this happens, and I know work arounds for it (most of the time I just use float) but my question is **why is there a space to begin with?**

Here is the fiddle I was messing around with :

### http://jsfiddle.net/6LftK/

if you change `.box` to `float: left;` the space goes away. Just really curious as to why there is a space in the first place.

Comment: Becuase you had spaces between the divs. Put them in one line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this revision: http://jsfiddle.net/6LftK/1/ and note that I've removed the space between the elements in the HTML. The `space` exists because there is whitespace in the HTML and `inline` elements respect that whitespace and that includes `inline-block` elements. By floating an element you have changed it from an `inline` element to a `block`.

```
<div id="manufactureLogos">
    <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Merely answering the question, but as you're aware there are better ways to solve it than smashing elements together.

Comment: You can get rid of the space by setting `font-size: 0;` on the container element so you don't have to string all your tags together.

Answer (score 0):

The reason there are spaces is because inline-block elements are treated like normal text, in the sense that they have whitespace. Some workarounds include using `font-size: 0` on the container and then resetting the font-size on the inline-block elements; using negative margins to collapse the space; or by altering your HTML to remove the whitespace.

[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) has a handy article on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to set **font-size** to **0** in **#manufactureLogos** so it will be like this

```
#manufactureLogos {
    width: 850px;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Also you should set **font-size** in **.box** so it will be like this

```
.box {
    background: gray;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Maybe this link will help you, it has more details

[Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Hope this will help you ...

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
    margin: -2px;
```

to `#manufactureLogos div {}` for a simple CSS trick to clear the white space generated by the spaces and line-breaks, and save your code syntax.

```
#manufactureLogos div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -2px;
}
```

But this only assumes the default character size for white-space is taking up 2 browser pixels.

Double insurance would be to use aaron's method and also default font size to 0.

```
#manufactureLogos div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -2px;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

#### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/9t6D8/)

Or as arronburows mentioned, you can set the containers `font-size: 0;`, effectively removing the whtie-space as well.